# searching for sequences in a FASTA format

Tags: python, regex, biopython, fasta

I am trying to look for multiple specific sequences in a DNA sequence within a FASTA format and then print them out. For simplicity, I made a short string sequence to show my problem.

```
import re
seq = "QPPLSK"
find_in_seq = re.search(r"[^P](P|K|R|H|W)", seq)
print find_in_seq.string[find_in_seq.start():find_in_seq.end()]
```

I only get one output of a match "QP" when there are 2 matches "QP" and "SK". How do I get to show the 2 matches instead of just only showing the first match?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and change the regex so that there is no more capturing group - `[^P](?:P|K|R|H|W)` or `[^P][PKRHW]`:

```
import re
seq = "QPPLSK"
find_in_seq = re.findall(r"[^P][PKRHW]", str(seq))
print(find_in_seq)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/E8Luuz)

Note that if you want to match any *letter* other than `P`, you'd better use `[A-OQ-Z]`.

Comment: Thank you but when trying the same method on a FASTA format that method does not work

Comment: If `seq` is a string, it will work. Try passing `str(seq)` as the input.

Comment: Yes I have and something like this [('A', 'S', 'T', 'Q'), ('F', 'W', 'J', 'M') is displayed instead of the sequences. The first matched sequence doesn't even show. I don't think it's a string even though I parsed it as a string using str. If it wasn't a string then wouldn't the re.search not work too.

Comment: I feel like such a dumbass I thought I had already changed the regex but I never. Thank you so much for helping.